# Can't Run Django Manage.py from Venv

Tags: python, django, pycharm, cookiecutter-django

I'm trying to run manage.py makemigrations for my django app, and I'm getting a "Couldn't import Django" message.

I know how venv works and I'm sure my environment includes Django. See below; I try to run manage.py (running into the error), and then I run $ django-admin --version, and it shows the version of Django.

```
    (venv) emmett@emmett-HP:~/PycharmProjects/onramp_crm$ sudo python manage.py makemigrations contacts
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 18, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
(venv) emmett@emmett-HP:~/PycharmProjects/onramp_crm$ django-admin --version
2.0.9
(venv) emmett@emmett-HP:~/PycharmProjects/onramp_crm$
```

This is a django-cookiecutter project using Pycharm Pro edition. I've deleted the onramp_crm/venv folder and completely reinstalled the venv, setting up a new interpreter in Pycharm as well. Logged out & restarted Ubuntu, restarted Pycharm, everything I can think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `sudo` from `sudo python manage.py makemigrations contacts`.

Using `sudo` will use your system version of Python, which, it seems, does not have Django installed. Without `sudo` you'll use the venv, which has Django.